# Save image to app album with UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiactivity

I am using UIActivityViewController to share and save images in my app. Right now, images get stored in global Camera roll. I want to save it to app's own album. 
To do that, I had to exclude UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll from UIActivityViewController and add my own custom SaveImageActivity. Now problem is that the activity comes at the last. How do I change the order to bring my custom UIActivity to the front?
Similar queries show that this is not possible to do. How is Dropbox app able to do it then?

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this?

Comment: my understanding is that the order is set by the user and you don't have control over it in absolute terms. Only your items relative to each other.